# How do I schedule a queue job synchronously on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, schedule

Pretty much what the title says, when I write this on `kernel.php`

```
$schedule->job(new Heartbeat)->everyFiveMinutes();
```

It runs the code asynchronously, is there anyway I could do a `dispatchNow()` on a schedule?

I am using Laravel 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `onConnection` method to set the driver on-the-fly.

```
$schedule->job((new Heartbeat)->onConnection('sync'))->everyFiveMinutes();
```

[Another option](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Schedule.php#L126) may be while calling the `job` method, setting the `connection`.

```
/**
 * Add a new job callback event to the schedule.
 *
 * @param  object|string  $job
 * @param  string|null  $queue
 * @param  string|null  $connection
 * @return \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent
 */
public function job($job, $queue = null, $connection = null)
{
    return $this->call(function () use ($job, $queue, $connection) {
        $job = is_string($job) ? Container::getInstance()->make($job) : $job;

        if ($job instanceof ShouldQueue) {
            $this->dispatchToQueue($job, $queue ?? $job->queue, $connection ?? $job->connection);
        } else {
            $this->dispatchNow($job);
        }
    })->name(is_string($job) ? $job : get_class($job));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Ersoy, is there by any chance I could call the ```dispatchNow()``` from the ```job``` method

Comment: @Lloen it should be dispatched immediately since it is using `sync` driver. Still, according to the snippet i shared If the Job is not instance of `ShouldQueue` it will call `dispatchNow`